# how do I int() a hour that start with 0?

Tags: python, datetime

I am working on a time calculator, every thing is ok but when the actual time have a 0 in front of the hours or the minutes(like this 09:08) it can't use int() proprealy how do I make this work? I already tried to use IFs o cut the string when is this situation, but it didn't work very well.

```
[...]
hour = int(input('hour')
minute = int(input('minute')

def chronus():
    MB = minute
    HB1 = hour
    HB = HB1 * 60
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
    own = str(now)
    nwo = own.split(':')
    ho,min = nwo[0],nwo[1]
    HA1 = int(xa,0)#here show the problem: invalid literal for int() with base 0:'09'<- the hour I 
                     did the code
    MA = int(xo,0)
    HA = HA1 * 60
    print(HA)
    print(MA)
    M1 =(HA + MA)
    M2 =(MB + HB)

    print(M1/60)
    print(M2/60)
    M3 = M2 - M1
    print(M3)
    print(M1)
    if M3 < 0:
        M5 = M3 * -1
        M4 = (1440 - M1) + M5
    print(M4)
[...]
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a base of `0` to `int`... just use `int` directly and it defaults to base 10... or explicitly pass base 10 to it if you really want?

Comment: Matching all your parentheses may help.

Comment: Why `int(xa,0)`? Why do you put a 0? The second parameter specify the base, it has nothing to do that the `xa` could start with a zero

Comment: Why are you parsing the string representation of the `datetime` value in the first place? Just access `now.hour` and `now.minute` directly. `now = datetime.datetime.now(); HA1 = now.hour; MA = now.minute`.

Comment: @chepner and then looking at the rest of the bits - kind of looks like it might be covered by what `timedelta` can do anyway...

Comment: ok my bad, When I was making the question I confused "xa, xo" from other code, It is "ho and min" sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
HA1 = int(xa,0) #here show the problem: invalid literal for int() with base 0:'09'<- the hour I
```

From the documentation, emphasis mine:

```
>>> help(int)
```

> Help on class `int` in module `builtins`:
>
> `class int(object)`
>
> `int([x])` -> integer
>
> `int(x, base=10)` -> integer
>
> Convert a number or string to an integer, or return `0` if no arguments
>
> are given.  If `x` is a number, return `x.__int__()`.  For floating point
>
> numbers, this truncates towards zero.
>
> If `x` is not a number or if `base` is given, then `x` must be a `str`ing,
>
> `bytes`, or `bytearray` instance representing an integer literal in the
>
> given `base`.  The literal can be preceded by `'+'` or `'-'` and be surrounded
>
> by whitespace.  **The `base` defaults to 10**.  Valid `base`s are `0` and
> `2`-`36`.
>
> **`Base 0` means to interpret the `base` from the string as an
> integer literal.**

In other words, the string `'09'` is parsed as if it were a literal in your Python code. And indeed:

```
>>> x = 09
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = 09
         ^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

It used to be that you could just prepend a `0` to an integer literal to specify octal, but this was deemed to be too confusing, so now `0o` is mandated, and a plain leading `0` is treated as an error (since either octal or decimal treatment would have caused backwards compatibility problems for some people, and a lot of confusion for others).

To interpret the number in base 10, just leave off the base entirely:

```
int('09') # evaluates to 9
```

However, it's very unclear why you are writing this code in the first place. Your code doesn't show where the value of `xa` comes from, and it seems like you *already had* the necessary `hour` and `minute` values - but if you need to extract them from a string that represents a time, that is what `strptime` is for. (Notice how you create the string with `strftime`? The `f` stands for `format`, and the `p` stands for `parse`.) And as others noted - if what you *really* want to do is to do arithmetic with time values, that is why the `timedelta` class exists.

Comment: realy thanks it halped me a lot, but I want to use the result for other thing, so timedelta wont help me,I realy apreciate ur answer!